# Mensagem de primeira visita no site

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho um sistema que sempre que o cliente faz o login, contabiliza mais uma visita, e na primeira visita aparece uma mensagem de boas vindas. Mas se o usuário recarregar a página novamente ou mudar de aba e voltar para a página principal, a mensagem de boas vindas aparece novamente. Ela só pára de aparecer se ele deslogar e logar novamente, o que incrementa o contador de visitas.

Pensei em colocar no botão de fechar da mensagem uma requisição para o banco de dados considerar a mensagem como vista e ela não aparecer mais, mas gostaria de saber se dá para fazer de alguma forma que o usuário logue, apareça a mensagem e quando ele mudar de aba ou recarregar a página, a mensagem desapareça definitivamente sem utilizar o banco de dados. É possível?

Comment: Qual o código que você usa para determinar se a mensagem deve ou não ser exibida? Isso é feito no front-end, no back-end, ou em ambos? Por enquanto o meu palpite é de que você pode alterar o contador de visitas imediatamente após determinar que a mensagem deve aparecer, assim qualquer visita seguinte não cai na mensagem. Mas se souber o código, dá pra ter uma ideia melhor.

Comment: Use uma SESSION com um valor único do usuário, como o ID dele ou e-mail. Quando ele logar, vc exibe a mensagem e cria a SESSION. Depois disso, coloque um código que verifica se a SESSION está ativa, caso esteja, não faz nada (não exibe a mensagem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer aqui. Obrigado pela ajuda, mas agora que eu vi que era mais fácil do que eu estava pensando. Fiz assim:

Na validação:

```
if($nVisitas->visitas >= 1){
        $contagem = $nVisitas->visitas + 1;

        $visitas = $conecta->prepare("update users set visitas = '$contagem' where email = '$email'");
        $visitas->execute();
                    }
```

Na pagina principal:

```
if($nVisitas->visitas == 0){
                echo "<p>Bem Vindo ao site!</p>";

                $visitas = $conecta->prepare("select * from users where email = '$email'" );
        $visitas->execute();
        $visitou = $visitas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


        $contagem = $visitou->visitas + 1;

        $visitante = $conecta->prepare("update users set visitas = '$contagem' where email = '$email'");
        $visitante->execute();

        }
```

Dessa forma, a primeira vez que o usuário logar, não vai incrementar na validação, só vai incrementar na página principal que vai dar uma visita depois que o código da mensagem já estiver na tela. Assim, quando eu mudo de aba ou recarrego a página, não mostra mais a mensagem, pois já incrementou uma visita. Coloquei aqui para ajudar alguém caso tenha a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

**O script abaixo só vai rodar se não houver uma session.**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['visitado'])){ 
   //mensagem boas vindas
   echo "Bem-vindo";
   //script para contabilizar visita
   //cria uma sessão
   $_SESSION['visitado'] = session_id();
}
```

> coloque o script dentro da validação do login